# Proj4rb: convert latitude/longitude to robinson projection

Tags: ruby, proj

I'm using the [Proj4rb](https://github.com/Caged/proj4rb) gem to convert latitude and longitude coordinates to a point in [Robinson projection](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/20/).  This will be used to figure out where to place a pin on a map image.

An example I'm trying (for New York) is:

```
  robinson_projection = Proj4::Projection.new('+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs')

  source_point = Proj4::Point.new(40.7142, -74.0064)
  source_projection = Proj4::Projection.new("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

  projected_point = source_projection.transform(robinson_projection, source_point)
```

This is throwing the following exception:

```
#<Proj4::LatitudeOrLongitudeExceededLimitsError: latitude or longitude exceeded limits>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors, curious if one is the cause:

New York has : lat/lon: 40.713956,-74.00528
First error:

New York has a negative longitude coordinate, your wrote 74.0064

Second:
The order of long, lat in Point.new(x,y) that should be long, lat, not vice versa
Please check with docu!

so correct is:

```
source_point = Proj4::Point.new(-74.0064, 40.7142);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within your source point (lat, lng). Try this:

```
robinson_projection = Proj4::Projection.new('+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs')

lat = 40.7142
lon = -74.0064
source_point = Proj4::Point.new(Math::PI * lon.to_f / 180,
                                Math::PI * lat.to_f / 180)
source_projection = Proj4::Projection.new("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

projected_point = source_projection.transform(robinson_projection, source_point)
```